# Adding some padding to UIBarButtonItems on a UIToolBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am looking to introduce some padding on the custom UIBarButtonItems that I'm placing on a custom UIToolBar.

It looks fine on an iPhone with UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, but on an iPad, it doesn't fill out appropriately.

[image]

This is my code:

```
UIToolbar *eventToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                      self.view.window.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];

    eventToolBar.items =   @[ [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wedding"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Birthday"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Anniversary"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Year"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                            target:nil
                                                                            action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Engagement"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(barButtonAddText:)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                  target:nil
                                                  action:nil],];
```

I know I have to do something like set it to Fixed, and set the width, but that's for creating UIBarButtonItems and then adding it to a UIToolBar. I'm creating my buttons directly on the UIToolBar and I'm not sure how to adjust the width for this.

Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the last flexible space. You only want space between buttons, not at either end.

Comment: Oh man - that's just brilliant. I didn't even think to do that. That fixed it in a heartbeat. Thanks so much @rmaddy